# How do I make the title a clickable link on tumblr post?

Tags: html, hyperlink, tumblr

I've been trying to figure this out for days, but basically, I'm trying to create it so that when I create a post on Tumblr, the title is clickable. At the moment, the only link is the tiny timestamp on the photo, and it's not obvious that some of my blog posts even exist.

I think this is the code I need to edit, but I can't work out exactly what I need to add:

```
<div class="inner">{block:Title}
            <h4>{Title}</h4>{/block:Title}
```

I've tried adding: `<a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a>` as suggested online, but that doesn't work at all. Can anyone help?

My website: http://wildwood-shore.tumblr.com

Comment: The code you have added is for the main title of the blog, not a post title. Photo posts don't support a title. https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#photo-posts